# How to save date/time every time a record (in CRUD) is opened?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

**[your opinion is needed]**

I'm planning to add this feature to a CRUD web api app i built, but for now, i'm planning the `timestamp feature`,

**For reporing purpose**

Save time `date/time` in `SQL` everytime a record is **open**.

***open***: *every time user views more details about record.*

What would be the best approach/practice for this?

Comment: Are you asking a software engineering question?  Or do you have some code?  SO is not some free SE service for you.

Comment: Are you planning to write to db everytime a query to a specific table happens? then a storage process can help you.

Comment: Starting your question with "*your opinion is needed*" on a forum that explicitly closes every **primarily opinion-based questions**? You might want to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Tersosauros Yes I'm asking a software engineering question, I don't have the code yet, just planning for now

Comment: @VincentZhang Aha! wrote that down, storage process! thank you

Comment: Have a separate log table where you record the user, time and the ID of the record that was opened?

Comment: @johna that's correct!